# Change <v-autocomplete> chip delete icon

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Autocomplete.vue

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    v-bind="$props"
    v-on="$listeners"
  >
    <!-- Cycling through slots -->
    <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots">
      <template :slot="name">
        <slot :name="name"></slot>
      </template>
    </template>

    <!-- Cycling through scoped slots -->
    <template
      v-for="(_, name) in $scopedSlots"
      #[name]="data"
    >
      <slot
        :name="name"
        v-bind="data"
      ></slot>
    </template>

  </v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
import { VAutocomplete } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {

  extends: VAutocomplete,

  props: {

    dense: {
      default: true
    },

    smallChips: {
      default: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

I want to change the trash icon.

I looked in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/), but I didn't find any prop able to directly change the icon. I might be wrong, and I hope so, but it could be necessary to access the item slot to change the icon.

If so, can anyone provide the necessary code to change the icon WITHOUT losing any feature/functionality?

Answer (score 0):

try the clear-icon prop.
from the documentation-

[image]

Comment: That prop refers to the outer icon, the one which removes every single chip.